Lack of range with Shimano CUES 2x11 derailleur
Update: I removed the "b-ring" washer that the B-screw rides against, that brought the derailleur closer to the cassette.     Shifting was 100%, but there is still a gap between the derailleur and the hanger, so it's not a rideable solution.
Options:
Grind down the B-ring to get it thinner?
Grind down the hanger to get it thinner?
???
I have a Canyon Roadlite that came with Shimano Cues 1x10 groupset.
I converted it to a Shimano Cues 2x11.
The components, per Shimano, are all compatible without spacers or wolf teeth or whatnot, but I cannot get the low (bigger) sprocket to engage.
From the looks of it, I run out of cable, but the H limit screw is jacked in pretty far to shift the pulleys over the 11t sprocket.
The hanger was initially bent inwards (toward the wheel) and before I straightened it, I could reach the low (45t) sprocket, but with a straight hanger, I run out of cable.
B-limit screw is set correctly to allow the jockey wheel to clear the sprocket.
L- Limit screw is not hitting, as I don't have enough cable pull to reach it.
I just recently lengthened the cable housing, but it didn't help.
Tightening the tension only messes up the shifting for the rest of the gears, but doesn't correct anything anyway.
Components:
Shimano Cues RD-U6020-11 Derailleur
Shimano CS-LG400-11 11-45t Cassette
Shimano FH-QC300-HM hub
Shimano SL-U6000-11R shifter
Updated with a comparison of the exact same groupset on my Cannondale compared to the Canyon. The Cannondale works great.
Cannondale distance from derailleur to first cog: 15mm
Canyon distance from derailleur to first cog: 17mm







Can you confirm that the shifter has 10 detents?

Yes it does. The last shift down just doesn't push far enough, even pushing after shift.

Are you sure the hanger was bent? The RD cage should not be perfectly straight when looking from front/rear, but i'm not sure about the direction.

I used a hanger alignment tool on it and dialed it in to within 1mm.
With this bike, the hanger moves inward when you tighten the QR skewer, so I did the alignment with it fully engaged.
I've added more images for clarity.
You can see the cage kicks outwards at the lower pulley.

Do not use any [SOLVED] to questions here. Instead, accept one of the answers or write your own and accept that one.

That bulge of the chain off the cog on the third can indicate that the chain is pretty worn, might need a new one.

brand new chain. The third pic shows the derailler at limit and the chain not reaching the outer cog.

I ended up grinding down the B-stop washer by 2mm, then had to align the hanger with the washer in place since I don't have access to a CNC mill.
Shifts are crisp and precise, and I can reach all gears.
Problem solved.

I don't think the cage kicking outwards looks right. Anyway, with the shifter on number 11 and cable detached from the rear derailleur the hanger should move to the smallest cog by itself and the H limiting screw adjusted with the chain running, right?  It's after the limiting screw is adjusted to satisfaction that the cable is then locked with some tension with the pinch bolt.  Then with shifter on number 10, the housing tension adjuster can be used to make sure the chain moves to the second smallest cog. Then all other gear shifting should fall in place. When the shifter is on nbr 1 use L.

Correct. This is how it’s configured. Currently, it works quite nicely as a 10 speed because the derailleur can’t reach that top sprocket.
The thing that gives me insight that the issue is an offset issue is how far in the H-limit needs to be to line up the smallest cog.
I can’t get the cassette out further because any spacer and the lock ring won’t engage.  The torque on the lock ring is at minimum (30-Nm) to not overload the spring washer behind the cassette.

What is the story here? If things were working fine before some accident (bending the hanger and maybe other parts) and now they do not work, then some part is still bent/twisted or broken even if you are convinced the hanger now is as it should be.
You could try to swap the deraileurs and see if the problem persists. If it persists then the hanger still isn't ok or the frame has been damaged. If the swap solves it, then the hanger is in fact ok and the deraileur bent/broken.

I'm building out a new bike (Canyon). This is a new-new bike, never been on the road new. Components are all new. The hanger could have been bent in shipping, or could have been set with a different skewer tension since it does seem sensitive to that. Dunno, but it shifted weird in the stand before I took it off, but I didn't worry about tuning it since...I was taking it off anyway.
The Cannondale is my wife's bike that I converted from a 1x9 to a 2x11 with no issues.

Perhaps it was meant to have a slight bend by design? Just speculation on my part, but the hangers I have seen have been pretty sturdy stuff and would require huge forces to bend unmounted withouth the leverage gained when mounted. And if the bike was shipped assembled, then an accident still applies. Anyway, I don't think I'm of any help here.

I’m starting to wonder that myself. The fact that the hanger can move so much depending in skewer tightness makes me question whether it’s functional. I have new hangers coming, so tbd.
